# Printing array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to print this array in Ruby. The output i get is 3 lines of this:

#Lod:0x0000000002690170>

If i use inspect i get it like this:

@lodnr="10000", @lobnr=" 150" and so on.

Here's my code

```
class Lod

attr_accessor :lodnr
attr_accessor :lobnr
attr_accessor :stknr

def initialize(lodnr, lobnr, stknr)
    @lodnr = lodnr
    @lobnr = lobnr
    @stknr = stknr.chomp
end

$sold = Array.new

input = File.open("lodsedler.txt", "r")
input.each do |line|
    l = line.split(',')
    $sold << Lod.new(l[0], l[1], l[2])
end

puts $sold

end
```

The input file looks like this

```
10000, 150, 5
500, 10, 1
8000, 171, 3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you try `p $sold` you may see more your problem.

The result is

```
[#<Lod:0x26d8fa0 @lodnr="10000", @lobnr=" 150", @stknr=" 5">, #<Lod:0x26d8ee0 @lodnr="500", @lobnr=" 10", @stknr=" 1">, #<Lod:0x26d8e20 @lodnr="8000", @lobnr=" 171", @stknr=" 3">]
```

You get an array of three LOD-objects.

There is no specific output defined for the Lod-objects, so the are printed in the technical version you see. With `to_s`you can define your own output.

Example:

```
class Lod

  attr_accessor :lodnr
  attr_accessor :lobnr
  attr_accessor :stknr

  def initialize(lodnr, lobnr, stknr)
      @lodnr = lodnr
      @lobnr = lobnr
      @stknr = stknr.chomp
  end

  def to_s
    "<Lod %8s, %5s, %3s>" % [@lodnr, @lobnr, @stknr]
  end
  def inspect; to_s; end
end

$sold = Array.new

DATA.each do |line|
  l = line.split(',')
  $sold << Lod.new(l[0], l[1], l[2])
end

p $sold
puts $sold
__END__
10000, 150, 5
500, 10, 1
8000, 171, 3
```

The output is:

```
[<Lod    10000,   150,   5>, <Lod      500,    10,   1>, <Lod     8000,   171,   3>]
<Lod    10000,   150,   5>
<Lod      500,    10,   1>
<Lod     8000,   171,   3>
```

You can adapt the `to_s` method for your preferred output.

Some remarks:

- You wrote your main coding (read file, create global data...) inside the class. That's bad coding.
- If you want the code inside the class, then you may use class variables instead the global variable.
- I replaced the external file with `__END__` and `DATA`. (makes it easier to make a MWE)
- Depending on ruby version the output differs (there are changes, how arrays are written).

Comment: Well it doesnt come out like that on my pc, it still says
[#<Lod:0x26d8fa0 @lodnr="10000", @lobnr=" 150", @stknr=" 5">, #<Lod:0x26d8ee0 @lodnr="500", @lobnr=" 10", @stknr=" 1">, #<Lod:0x26d8e20 @lodnr="8000", @lobnr=" 171", @stknr=" 3">]

Comment: Did you copy my Code and tried it with my code?? I guess you defined the `to_s` outside the class. Which ruby version do you use? what happens if you define also a `inspect`-method like the to_s?

Comment: I just tried copying your code and run it. Output is still [#Lod:0x000000002353138 @lodnr="10000", @lobnr=" 150", @stknr=" 5">, #<Lod:0x000 and so on. I run ruby 2.0.0p247. Windows 8 64 bit mode.

Comment: If i made the inspect method correct the output is:
[[...], [...], [...], [...]]
Lod 10000, 150, 5
Lod 500, 10, 1 and then the last 2

Comment: My output used ruby 1.9.3. I modified the code, so inspect and to_s return the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Add to_s definition to class Lod:

```
class Lod
  def to_s
    "#{@lodnr} #{@lobnr}  #{@stknr}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Well it doesnt come out like that on my pc, it still says [#<Lod:0x26d8fa0 @lodnr="10000", @lobnr=" 150", @stknr=" 5">, #<Lod:0x26d8ee0 @lodnr="500", @lobnr=" 10", @stknr=" 1">, #<Lod:0x26d8e20 @lodnr="8000", @lobnr=" 171", @stknr=" 3">]